# Excel VBA - Change cell value dynamically based on the value in two columns

Tags: excel, vba

i worte a vba code to change cell value dynamically based on the values entered in two columns. But the code is not working.

Kindly anyone help me to get to know the process.

Thanks

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Long

If Not Intersect(Range("G:H"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each rng In Intersect(Range("G:H"), Target)
        r = rng.Row
        If Range("G" & r) = 5 And Range("H" & r) = "A" Then
            Range("I" & r) = "M"
            Range("I" & r).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        ElseIf Range("G" & r) = 5 And Range("H" & r) = "B" Then
            Range("I" & r) = "H"
            Range("I" & r).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Else
            Range("I" & r).Interior.ColorIndex = 0                                  
        End If
    Next rng
End if
End Sub
```

Comment: "But the code is not working" is not very specific. Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53637041/edit) to let us know what the expected result is and how your code fails to achieve it? [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may  be useful

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you execute Range("I" & r) =  you fire the worksheet change event again, and again and again . If you want to change cells in a change event you need to turn the change event off within the routine

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = false
```

and then turn it on at the end

```
Application.EnableEvents = true
End Sub
```

Comment: Technically Ok in this case since the event handler only updates Column I, and changes in that column are filtered out by the `Intersect()`.  For sure though you need events turned back on ;-) - preferrably you have an error handler to ensure this happens in case anything goes wrong.